# How Input Multiple row using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, input, sum

I created a table showing the student's name and nis. How do I enter the value in each form and display the sum in the n.akhir form? I want if you click the save button, the summation will be processed and entered into the database.
I have tried several times but always failed

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
<tr>  
    <th>No</th>                         
    <th>NAMA</th>           
    <th>UH 1</th>
    <th>UH 2</th>
    <th>UH 3</th>
    <th>UH 4</th>
    <th>N.AKHIR</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($siswa as $row){
                
     echo "<tr>  <td width='100'>$row->nis</td>
                 <td>".  strtoupper($row->nama)."</td>
                 <td width='150'><input type='int'  id='ulangan_1".$row->nis."'  class='form-control'></td>

                 <td width='150'><input type='int'  id='ulangan_2".$row->nis."'  class='form-control'></td>

                 <td width='150'><input type='int'  id='ulangan_3".$row->nis."'  class='form-control'></td>

                 <td width='150'><input type='int'  id='ulangan_4".$row->nis."'  class='form-control'></td>

                 <td width='150'><input type='int'  id='nilai_akhir".$row->nis."' class='form-control'></td>
                
                            
                            </tr>";
            } ?>  </table>
```

> and here the javascript

```
$('#btn_save').on('click',function(nis){
                var ulangan_1 = $('#ulangan_1'+nis).val();
                var ulangan_2 = $('#ulangan_2'+nis).val();
                var ulangan_3 = $('#ulangan_3'+nis).val();
                var ulangan_4 = $('#ulangan_4'+nis).val();
                var nilai_akhir  = ulangan_1 + ulangan_2 + ulangan_3 + ulangan_4 / 4;
                $("#nilai_akhir"+nis).val(nilai_akhir);
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/nilai/update_nilai')?>",
                    dataType : "JSON",
                    data : {nis:nis , jadwal:<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3)?>, ulangan_1:ulangan_1, ulangan_2:ulangan_2, ulangan_3:ulangan_3, ulangan_4:ulangan_4,nilai_akhir:nilai_akhir},
                    success: function(data){
                        //$("#dataSiswa").html(html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: One thing is - when using site_url() you do not need to add index.php in your AJAX URL. What do you see when you view the generated HTML Source in your browser? Does it all look correct as you expect?

Comment: @Zerra Triani your problem is solved or not?

Comment: still not yet @KUMAR